# Как динамически добавить объект в Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Мало добавить, нужно чтоб еще и отрисовался.
По сабжу нашел пример

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.Fill = Brushes.Red;
    rectangle.Width = 100;
    rectangle.Height = 100;
    Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, 0);
    Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 0);
    canvas1.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

В свойстве самого canvas1, элемент лежит, но на экране ничего не отображает.

Может, свойства элемента в самом XAML надо корректировать? Или как еще можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А сам canvas где находится? На панель/popup, или что там у вас, его добавили?

Comment: Этот кусок кода у него засекречен. Очень много стоит, поэтому вопрос только из категории - а правда что по справке элемент на канвас добавляется так?

Comment: Аффтар, ау! Спросил и пропал. Последнее посещение было 16-го числа, лол.

Comment: По идее, должно работать и в том виде, как написано в топике...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у тебя прямоугольник сливается с фоном, просто измени его цвет